# why cant i get my "def" functions to output text correctly?

Tags: python

When I run my script there is no output. It just does not output any text.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

def main_menu():
    print "this is the main menu"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Functions don't do anything unless you call them.

Comment: you need to call the function inorder to execute it.
calling `main_menu` will print from that function

Comment: Function don't trigger unless you invoked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you just declared the function and never called it. Try this:

```
def main_menu():
      print ("This is main menu")
main_menu()
```

I hope this helps. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

def main_menu():
    print "this is the main menu"

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main_menu()
```

Comment: No idea why this was down-voted (Except maybe it could use more explanation). It's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function in your script.

The simplest way would be to add this below your function definition

```
main_menu()
```